# 'generic_inlineformset_factory' produces " 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta' "

Tags: django, django-views, django-contenttypes

I can not save my front-end choices using `generic_inlineformset_factory`.

If I do not select anything in front-end, the line `sports = sports_formset.save(commit=False)` does not produce any errors, but if I choose anything, I get `'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'`

The `# PROBLEM PART` at the bottom of the code.

```
# models
class M2MProfilesToSportTypeGroups(models.Model):
    MASTERY_CHOICES = (
        (1, _('newby')),
        (2, _('amateur')),
        (3, _('semi-pro')),
        (4, _('pro'))
    )

    mastery = models.IntegerField(_('mastery'), null=True, blank=True, choices=MASTERY_CHOICES)
    sport_type_group = models.ForeignKey(SportTypesGroups, verbose_name=_('sport type group'))

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

# views
class CompanyProfileCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'profiles/create_n_update.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        profile_form = CompanyProfileForm()  #show_criterias=False)

        PlaceTypeFormSet = inlineformset_factory(CompanyProfiles, M2MCompanyProfilesToPlaceTypeGroups,
                                                 fields='__all__', can_delete=False)

        SportTypeFormSet = generic_inlineformset_factory(M2MProfilesToSportTypeGroups,
                                                         can_delete=False)

        places_formset = PlaceTypeFormSet()
        sports_formset = SportTypeFormSet()

        return self.render_to_response({'form': profile_form,
                                        'places_formset': places_formset,
                                        'sports_formset': sports_formset})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        profile_form = CompanyProfileForm(data=request.POST)


        PlaceTypeFormSet = inlineformset_factory(CompanyProfiles, M2MCompanyProfilesToPlaceTypeGroups,
                                                 fields='__all__', can_delete=False)

        SportTypeFormSet = generic_inlineformset_factory(M2MProfilesToSportTypeGroups,
                                                         can_delete=False)

        places_formset = PlaceTypeFormSet(data=request.POST)
        sports_formset = SportTypeFormSet(data=request.POST)

        if profile_form.is_valid() and places_formset.is_valid() and sports_formset.is_valid():
            profile_form.instance.created_by = request.user
            company_profile = profile_form.save()

            places = places_formset.save(commit=False)
            for place in places:
                place.company_profile = company_profile
                place.save()

            # PROBLEM PART
            sports = sports_formset.save(commit=False)
            for sport in sports:
                obj.content_object = company_profile
                obj.save()

            return redirect(company_profile)

        return self.render_to_response({'form': profile_form,
                                        'places_formset': places_formset,
                                        'sports_formset': sports_formset})
```

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution.

The `# PROBLEM PART` is changed:

```
sports_formset = SportTypeFormSet(data=request.POST, instance=company_profile)
sports_formset.save()
```

Providing `company_profile` we let Django to find out, what kind of `content_type` and `object_id` to use.